# stopping list expansion while pressing a button

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

i made a programm that reads a binary file, converts the hex numbers into different C types and writes those converted numbers in files. So i used list comprehension for the most part and i made a GUI to access options on what to write into the file. In the end the user presses the a button after choosing the options and the data processing starts, followed by the creation of the files. Everything works fine unless i press the button multiple times. The new files that got created contain the old data and the new data depending on the options of course. So i figured out that the lists i am creating aren´t getting overwritten or cleared as i hoped but expanded. I have a lot of lists so deleting them manually by name is rather annoying. Is there a better way or method or something to solve this problem?

I will include code, but only a small portion of it.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import messagebox
from struct import unpack
from codecs import decode

class Graphicaluserinterface(tk.Frame):

    inputliste = []

    def __init__(self,master=None):
        super().__init__(master)
        self.grid()
        self.fileopenname = tk.StringVar()
        self.filesavename  =tk.StringVar()
        self.entrystring = tk.IntVar()
        self.taktzykluszeit = tk.DoubleVar()
        self.taktunterschiedboolean = tk.BooleanVar()
        self.menubar = tk.Menu(self)
        self.create_widgets()
        self.entrystring.set(9)
        self.taktzykluszeit.set(0.0)
        self.taktunterschiedboolean.set(False)

    def create_widgets(self):
        self.programmstart = tk.Button(self, text = "Start Program")
        self.programmstart.grid(row=10,column=8,sticky = "W")
        self.programmstart["command"]=lambda:[self.fileselectwarning(),self.writealldatafile(),self.writeselecteddata()]

    def zugriffaufdatenverarb(self):
        #this is the method that accesses the data processing methods

        inputfilepath2 = self.fileopenname.get()
        self.inputfilepath = inputfilepath2
        a = Trennzeichenalgorithmus
        a.fileopening123(self)
        a.trennzeichenmethode(self)
        b = Datenverarbeitung
        b.uhrzeitdermessung(self)
        b.drehzahl(self)
        b.temperatursensoren(self)
        b.analogvoltsensoren(self)
        b.analogmilliampsensoren(self)
        b.drehmomentsensoren(self)

    def writealldatafile(self):
        import csv
        from itertools import zip_longest
        outputfilepath2 = self.filesavename.get()
        self.outputfilepath = outputfilepath2
        allelisten = [self.datumstring,self.ganzesdatum,self.milliundmikroliste_3,self.drehzahlgsm1_4,self.drehmomentgsm1_4,
                  self.drehzahlgsm2_4,self.drehmomentgsm2_4]
        column_titles = []
        column_titles.append("Datum")
        column_titles.append("")
        column_titles.append("Taktzykluszeit in s")
        column_titles.append("Drehzahl_GSM_1 in 1/min")
        column_titles.append("Drehmoment_GSM_1 in Nm")
        column_titles.append("Drehzahl_GSM_2 in 1/min")
        column_titles.append("Drehmoment_GSM_2 in Nm")
        for j in range(len(self.analogvolt_3)):
            column_titles.append("Analogvoltsensor"+"_"+str(j+1)+" in +-10V")
            allelisten.append(self.analogvolt_3[j])
        for l in range(len(self.analogmilliamp_3)):
            column_titles.append("Analogamperesensor"+"_"+str(l+1)+" in 20 mA")
            allelisten.append(self.analogmilliamp_3[l])
        for i in range(len(self.thermoelement_3)):
            column_titles.append("Thermoelement"+"_"+str(i+1)+" in °C")
            allelisten.append(self.thermoelement_3[i])
        for k in range(len(self.pt100element_3)):
            column_titles.append("Pt-100-Element"+"_"+str(k+1)+" in °C")
            allelisten.append(self.pt100element_3[k])
        column_titles_tuple = tuple(column_titles)
        export_data1 = zip_longest(*allelisten, fillvalue = "")
        with open(self.outputfilepath,"w+",encoding="ISO-8859-1") as csvwithalldata:
        alldata=csv.writer(csvwithalldata,delimiter=";")
        alldata.writerow(column_titles_tuple)
        alldata.writerows(export_data1)
        csvwithalldata.close()

root = tk.Tk()
app = Graphicaluserinterface(master=root)
app.master.title("Test")
app.master.minsize(800,300)
root.config(menu=app.menubar)
app.mainloop()
```

The method "writealldatafile" implements all the data processing lists together into one list that gets written into the file. If you need more code or elaboration on my code let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Ok i think i found a simple solution. When the binary file is read, a list is created with the hex values. This list then is used to create all other lists that at some point are written into the output files. Therefore using the del command on this first list, that is created solved my problem.